# Dynamically fetched new value from trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create trigger dynamically inserting audit logs based on columns returned from cursor:  audited_column_cursor('managed_content').

I don't know how get current column value from new object version.

Example:

- this is the way i get value when i pass column name static: NEW.version_id
- i want to get value based on dynamic column name, using current cursor value table_column.column_name: new.table_column.column_name

```
CREATE FUNCTION proc_managed_content_audit_insert()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $managed_content_audit$
DECLARE
table_column   RECORD;
table_columns refcursor;
audit_table_id integer;
BEGIN
  table_columns := audited_column_cursor('managed_content');
  LOOP
    FETCH table_columns INTO table_column;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    SELECT id INTO audit_table_id FROM audit_table where change_object_type = 'managed_content';
    INSERT INTO audit_action(change_type, username, change_object_id, column_name, old_value, new_value,
    audit_table_id)
    VALUES ('INSERT', 'test-user', NEW.id, table_column.column_name,
    old.current_content_version_id, new.table_column.column_name(PROBLEMATIC), audit_table_id);

  END LOOP;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$managed_content_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Why not us a JSON based audit trigger? Like e.g. [this](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-changes-in-postgresql/) or [this](http://8kb.co.uk/blog/2015/01/19/copying-pavel-stehules-simple-history-table-but-with-the-jsonb-type/)

Comment: I want to audit only changed columns (frontend requirements - who changed specific field, when, old/new value)

Comment: That can easily be done with the JSONB solutions (see the second link in my comment)

Comment: ok, i'm trying to solve problem this way - but do you have any idea how ingore column i don't want to audit through this JSONB?

Comment: Just remove them: `some_jsonb_value - '{id,created_at}'::text[]`